# Determing the End with a Bool function

Tags: c++, boolean

I am trying to create a Play() function (think like a media player type play) that checks first to make sure that the given object isn’t at the end of its selections (if it is, the user will be told to rewind.)

I have a bool function called IsCAtEnd(). It’s supposed to find out if C is at the end. Right now I have something like this in it:

```
bool AC::IsCAtEnd()
{
CAtEnd = (CurrentSelect == NumOfSelect)
if (CAtEnd)
{return true;}
else
{return false;}
}
```

And in my Play() function I have something like this –

```
void AC::Play()
{
int Choice;
cout << Enter Selection to Play: “;
cin >> Choice;

CurrentSelection = Choice;
If (IsCAtEnd())
{
cout << “You need to rewind first.” << endl;
}
else
{
cout << “Playing “ << CurrentSelection << endl;
}
```

It compiles and runs but not as I’d like it too. For one, if I enter the last selection (Say C has 6 selections and I want to play the last one) it will tell me to rewind. 
Instead, I want it to play that selection and the next time Play is called tell me to rewind (recalling that the last time Play was called, it was on the last selection). I also want it to continue to prompt the user to rewind until they do so (so no calling play again, choosing a different selection and having that selection play).

I know I need to make it so that if the last selection is put in, the CAtEnd variable is changed to true after it is played. That way the next time around it’ll state that it needs to be rewound. I’m not sure how to do it though.

Comment: Your whole `IsCAtEnd` function took me several moments to parse in my mind. `return CurrentSelect == NumOfSelect;` is so much easier to understand.

Comment: what is CAtEnd in your is IsCAtEnd() function? Is it supposed to be bool CAtEnd? And what chris said, the body of that function only needs to be one line.

Comment: Changed the code to that. 

And yes CAtEnd is a variable declared in the class `bool CAtEnd`
After clearing out the function, I'm thinking I should be using this variable for the continued rewind prompt I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to play it first for any choice. 
Then check whether it is the last one or not. if it is last one, you prompted the rewind message, otherwise, do nothing.

you can change it like this

```
if(currentSelection <= NumberOfSelection)
{
     cout << “Playing “ << CurrentSelection << endl;
}

If (IsCAtEnd())
{
     cout << “You need to rewind first.” << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That definitely helped my last selection not being played. However, I still have the issue of Play allowing you to play a different selection the next time you call it (as opposed to tell you to rewind because last time the last selection was played.)

I cleared up my bool function the way chris pointed out though, and I still have the bool variable (bool CAtEnd) to use. Is there a way I can use this in getting them to rewind before playing any selections?

Comment: Do you want user to which one to play when you prompt the rewind msg?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the program to continuous run and with user input when prompting rewind msg, you can have a while loop

```
    int Choice;    
    cout << Enter Selection to Play: “;
    cin >> Choice;

    while(choice != 0)
    {

         CurrentSelection = Choice;

         if(currentSelection <= NumberofSelection)
             cout << “Playing “ << CurrentSelection << endl;

        if (IsCAtEnd())
        {
            cout << “You need to rewind first.” << endl;
            cout << Enter Selection to Play: “;
            cin >> Choice;
        }
}
```

Comment: Ah I understand now! I think I don't want this exactly. I want for Play to be completely unavailable until the user rewinds.

So I'm thinking something along the lines of:
`//while CAtEnd is true (C is at the end)
 cout << "Please Rewind."
 else, continue on with the regular play functions.